# DataTable losing thead and tbody tags on reload with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I am building a dynamic DataTable(.net) which contains an aspx Gridview within it. In one of the Gridview columns I have an aspx Button which uses the CommandEvent to send the click event and parameter to code behind. After processing, the button method should open a modal, which contains a table in it, which displays over the DataTable.

**Code Behind**

```
protected void btnTRCInfo_Click(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        PendingAndSelectedTRCS PST = new PendingAndSelectedTRCS();

        //Not Pager command Argument 
        if (e.CommandName != "Page")
        {
            PST.ownChange = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            string[] values = PST.ownChange.Split(',');

            Year = values[0];
            trcNo = values[1];
            Code = values[2];

            if (e.CommandName == "OwnerChange"){
                    TRCListingDetail TLD = new TRCListingDetail();
                    DataSet ds = TLD.GetDataSet(Year, trcNo, Code);

                    GetOwnerChangeData(ds, stateCode);

                    //gdvPSTrc.Visible = false;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "openModal('mdlOwnerChange');", true);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

**This is the Gridview HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table">    
            <asp:GridView 
                id="gdvPSTrc" 
                runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="dsPSTrc" 
                OnRowDataBound="gdvPSTrc_RowCreated"
                OnRowCommand="btnTRCInfo_Click"
                CssClass="table table-hover table-striped trcTable" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center"
                AllowPaging="false" 
                AllowSorting="false"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                GridLines="None" 
                ShowFooter="true" 
                Width="100%"
                BorderStyle="none" 
                SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="selected">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<center>TAX YEAR</center>" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"><%-- HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightGray" FooterStyle-BackColor="LightGray"--%>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("YEAR") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<center>OWNER CHANGE</center>" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"><%-- HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightGray" FooterStyle-BackColor="LightGray"--%>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button id="btnOwnerChange" 
                                runat="server" 
                                type="button"
                                CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs" 
                                data-container="body" 
                                data-toggle="modal" 
                                CommandName="OwnerChange" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("YEAR") + "," + Eval("TRC_NO") + "," + Eval("CODE") %>'
                                Text="+" 
                                UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                 </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:objectdatasource id="dsPSTrc" runat="server" selectmethod="GetDataSet" typename="PCTO.TTCS.PASTRC" />
```

**This is the modal the button opens from the code behind**

```
<div class="modal fade viewport" id="mdlOwnerChange" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close hidden" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button><center><h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Title3" /></h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOwnerChangeTitle" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
                        <div class="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <asp:Table ID='tblOwnerChange' runat='server' CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><%--OnRowDataBound="gdvOwnerChange_RowCreated" DataSourceID="dsOC"--%>
                                        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                                            <asp:TableHeaderCell BackColor="LightGray" Width="10%" ><center>
                                                <asp:Label Text='RECORDED' runat="server" /></center>
                                            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                            <asp:TableHeaderCell BackColor="LightGray" Width="10%" ><center>
                                                <asp:Label Text='SEQUENCE' runat="server" /></center>
                                            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                                        <asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableCell>
                                                <asp:Label ID='lblRecorded' runat='server' />
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                            <asp:TableCell>
                                                <asp:Label ID='lblSequence' runat='server' />
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                    </asp:Table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I keep getting an js mData error when the page reloads from the attempted datatable reload and modal opening. When I view the source of the Datatable/Gridview before the column button click event, the thead and tbody tags are present. But once I click the column button, the page reloads and the Datatable/Gridview is now missing the thead/tbody which in return throws the mData error.

**JS**

```
var tblTRCs = $('#cphPage_gdvPSTrc').DataTable({
    ordering: false, //turn sorting on/off
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 'All']], 
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRow
        }
    },
    stateSave: true, 
    stateDuration: -1 
});

//OPEN MODAL FUNCTION
function openModal(parm) {
$('#' + parm).modal('show');};
```

And finally the modal never displays during any of these events. If I look at the code behind its there with its table and data in it, its ready to go, but the openModal function is not working properly for this particular modal. Could this have to do with the timing of the reload or is it displaying behind the page somewhere?

Comment: I Solved most of my issue, I ended up adding the code behind method that specifically set up the <thead> and <tfoot> within each button click method. That way the <thead> and <tbody> are present on reload. Now I just need to solve for the problem of the page reloading AFTER the modal has alrealy opened. any suggestions there?

Comment: Final portion solved, I was originally using a ScriptManager which was loading the modal before the refresh. I did a little research and found a forum to try the ClientScript method instead to access the openModal js method. All is working well.